# Passing parameters to a UINavigationController's main view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitabcontroller

i'm pretty new in the iPhone/iPad developing. In my application i have a uitabcontroller and in one tab, i'll add a uinavigation controller. But I realized that i need the same design and function in other tab, I would like the reuse the code and the only change would be the xml file that the section is using.

Is there anyway to add a parameter in a uinavigation controller for the main view? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subclass `UINavigationController`, add in the common code, and have all your tab's view controllers use this subclass. So, for example, you could do:

```
@implementation MyNavController : UINavigationController {
    NSString *foo;
}

- (id)initWithFoo:(NSString *)aFoo;

@end
```

And implement `initWithFoo` like:

```
- (id)initWithFoo:(NSString *)aFoo {
    if (self = [super init]) { // or whatever init method you want to use for UINavigationController
        foo = [aFoo retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I think i got it. Instead of adding the navigation controller using the Interface Builder, I will add it manually by code. Will try this!

Comment: Well, you could use Interface Builder. Granted, I personally don't use it myself, but you could tie an IB object to a class that subclasses a common parent class.